# Can You Change The Color Of The Selection View In A SwiftUI Picker

Tags: swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI project and building a form that has a custom color theme. I've had a lot of success with Lists, NavigationViews etc when it comes to changing color. The Form & Picker seems to be quite difficult and I'm not sure it's possible.

I've been able to style the form view but when the picker is selected the row immediately turns back to the original color and the secondary view with the picker selection list is black. Upon return to the form the row stays black. The video below shows what I mean. My code is below. Is there a way to customize the colors of the secondary view and the form row?

```
struct SeafoodFilterView: View {
    
    // TestData
    var seafoods = ["Atlantic Salmon", "Atlantic Lobster", "Jumbo Sea Scallops", "Chilean Sea Bass"]
    
    @State private var selectedSeafood = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        // Used for PacificBlue color.
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
        UITableView.appearance().separatorColor = UIColor(Color.white)
        
        return NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.pacificBlue
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                Form {
                    //Section {
                    Picker(selection: $selectedSeafood, label: Text("Seafood").font(.custom(Fonts.gse, size: 18)).fontWeight(.semibold).foregroundColor(.white)) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< seafoods.count) {
                            Text(self.seafoods[$0])
                        } // ForEach
                    } // Picker
                    .listRowBackground(Color.pacificBlueAccent)
                } // Form
            } // ZStack
            .navigationTitle("Filters")
        } // NavigationView
    } // View
}
```

**Initial View Load**
[image]

**Secondary View**
[image]

**After View Returns**
[image]

Comment: Simply a mistake. Sorry.

Comment: No problem. I'll delete my comment! And sincerely hope you find an answer.